# Election page formatting bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown, election

On the Election page, the column on the right (containing some stats, a text box beginning with the phrase "In the election phase, 10 candidates...", **and any votes you've cast**) overlaps the candidates' blurbs.

Screenshot of text box overlap:

> [image: Picture of bug]

Just the votes, after scrolling down:

> [image: Picture of bug]

Only the first blurb is obscured by the text box (and, admittedly, only slightly obscured - The box is semitransparent), but the votes scroll with you all the way down the page.

The [Electronics election page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election) demonstrates the bug right now, if you've already voted.

Browsers:
Chrome 11, FF 4, Windows XP
Safari 5, FF 4, Mac OS X 10.6

Bumping this because, hopefully, some of the devs will be willing and able to vote on the Stack Overflow election, making it no longer [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), and fix the bug.

Comment: No repro here on IE8 on XP, but I can't vote so I don't know whether or not that'd impact it.

Comment: No repro FF4 or IE8 on Win7; same caveat as @Grace

Comment: I reproduced it on FF4 on XP, but only after logging in (and I have voted).  No repro without the login, though.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with any browsers on Win7. I don't have XP atm to test it though.

Comment: @Jin - Did you vote?

Comment: I get this error as well in safari on OS X. I have no zooming on the page.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome and Firefox on Win7

Comment: FWIW I repro'd this last year and thought I had told the dev's and they had looked at it. I believe it was Jin I told.

Comment: @jcolebrand - It's still status-norepro, though, so it's unlikely to get much more attention.

Comment: @Kevin ~ Nah, I just need to wait till the next time I do elections and I'll give them a walkthrough on the repro issue. I'm not sure when that will be, sadly enough. But see the comments below, it's status repro when we know what to tell the team.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Can't they just start an election on their test instance?  I think part of the reason that this hasn't been reproduced is that they (the devs) don't want to participate in an election (thus skewing the results) just to reproduce a minor formatting bug.

Comment: @Kevin - I really doubt that.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Math.SE election has come and gone, and this bug is still [meta-tag:status-norepro].

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't participate on that one, still waiting for one I can that I remember to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't repro this in Windows 7 at all:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- IE9

all look fine, either logged in or logged out.

It could be some kind of font issue with your installation of Windows XP, but that font list is very generic.

Are you "zooming" the page or fonts in any way?

Comment: No, I am not zooming at all. It only occurs after a vote has been cast, which places a new element at the right side of the page.  Did you do that?

Comment: @reem ah, that helps clarify

Comment: Norepro in the current election, either, so it seems to have been fixed.